# C++: gcc 'typename' may not be specified here (C/C++)

Tags: c++, gcc

I have this following code:

```
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template  <class Items>  void
    typename KernelT<Items>::
    _fix_halfedge_order(const HalfedgeHandle& _hh0, const HalfedgeHandle& _hh1) {
        //����������õ�������̰�ߵ���Ϊ�����ڽӹ�ϵ;  ����: ������̵İ�ߺ�
        HalfedgeHandle  fore_begin,          fore_end(_hh0);
        HalfedgeHandle  this_begin(_hh1),    this_end;
        HalfedgeHandle  back_begin(next_halfedge_handle(_hh0));
        HalfedgeHandle  back_end  (prev_halfedge_handle(_hh1));
```

And Visual Studio is complaining that: 'typename' may not be specified here (C/C++).

It's a small library when I try to build it with g++ tons of errors, gcc should work according to authors, but I am getting this error..

Comment: There exists no such thing as "C/C++". This is clearly C++. Are you compiling it as C or what? Because that would explain your problems.

Comment: First of all where did you get this code from? What are you supposed to do with it? Are you sure you haven't fallen into a [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) trap? And also remember that C and C++ are two *Very* different languages, the code you show is C++ and not valid C.

Comment: For more helpful responses in future be sure to provide a [mre] and the full compiler output

Comment: The code as shown is invalid and we can't fix it because it is too small of a fragment. You need to ask the author of the code. For this particular error, try removing `typename`, but no guarantees.